# Gensim (word2vec) retrieve n most frequent words

Tags: gensim

How is it possible to retrieve the n most frequent words from a Gensim `word2vec` model? As I understand, the frequency and count are not the same, and I therefore can't use the `object.count()` method.

I need to produce a list of the n most frequent words from my `word2vec` model.

Edit:

I've tried the following:

```py
w2c = dict()
for item in model.wv.vocab:
   w2c[item]=model.wv.vocab[item].count
w2cSorted=dict(sorted(w2c.items(), key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True))
w2cSortedList = list(w2cSorted.keys())
```

My initial guess was to use code above, but this implements the count method. I'm not sure if this represents the most frequent words.

Comment: What have you tried? Demonstrate some effort in solving the problem and provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `.count` property of each vocab-entries is the count of that word as seen during the initial vocabulary-survey. So sorting by that, and taking the highest-`count` words, will give you the most-frequent words.

But also, for efficiency, it's typical practice for the ordered-list of known-words to be ordered from most- to least-frequent. You can view this at the list `model.wv.index_to_key`, so can retrieve the 100 most frequent words by `model.wv.index_to_key[:100]`. (In Gensim before version 4.0, this same list was called either `index2entity` or `index2word`.)